# Getting “Gem::LoadError: can't activate jwt (~> 0.1.4), already activated jwt-1.0.0.”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I’m getting ‘Gem::LoadError: can't activate jwt (~> 0.1.4), already activated jwt-1.0.0.’ error when I tried to run a Cucumber-Ruby test. I’ve the following entries on my Gemfile.lock

```
jwt (1.0.0)
...
signet (0.4.5)
   addressable (>= 2.2.3)
   faraday (~> 0.8.1)
   jwt (>= 0.1.5)
   multi_json (>= 1.0.0)
```

I’ve jwt-1.0.0 installed. Any ideas how to resolve this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Signet gem (for me, called as a dependency of Google API Client) is being naughty and specifying the JWT gem version outside of it's Gemspec.

```
# in lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb line 25
gem 'jwt', '~> 0.1.4'
require 'jwt'
```

Use the Github version of Signet gem in your Gemfile, which has this rogue call removed.

```
gem 'signet', git: "https://github.com/google/signet.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back jwt explicitly in your Gemfile, something like this:

```
gem 'jwt', '~> 0.1.13'
```

I had a similar problem with google-api-client rather than signet: Gemfile.lock had `jwt (>= 0.1.5)` when the google-api-client Gemfile said `'jwt', '~> 0.1.5'` and the Gemfile.lock probably should have followed that.  The Gemfile change above makes sure that jwt really is `~> 0.1.5` and doesn't hit 1.*.